# Windows software for recording multiple video/audio sources?

Tags: software-recommendation, live-recording

I'm looking into options for recording video game sessions, including multiple different video and audio sources. I'm only at the planning stage of this, but here is basically what I want to set up:

- Have PC set up as recording hub for gameplay sessions either on same PC or on nearby game console
- Capture game footage, both audio and video, either capturing PC game footage or via capture hardware for console games (PCI or USB connection)
- Capture footage of players, probably via webcam attached to PC
- Capture both game and players feeds simultaneously

I'm fairly new to a lot of this stuff, so I'm not particularly sure what I'm looking for here. Can anyone provide some recommendations of software/hardware that would work for what I'm trying to do?

UPDATE: I've just discovered Telestream's [Wirecast](http://www.telestream.net/wirecast/overview.htm). It seems to be the sort of software I'm looking for, and I can use it to stream or save it to disk. It also has support for some Blackmagic Intensity capture hardware, which I was already looking at. Has anyone had experience with it or seen a similar, possibly cheaper alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I would try using a video recording interface with RCA connectors, as most TVs have an RCA audio/video output. Most of these connect via USB and come with some sort of software. For the video of the players, use a second software program and webcam/etc. to capture this. If you had a Mac, this could probably be sync'd in Final Cut Pro. I'm not familiar with all the software for Windows.

The main part I don't think you'll be able to accomplish (without expensive software) is capturing all of this in-sync with each device. This would require some sort of video-switcher software, similar to what TV stations use for live broadcasts. The method above is probably your cheapest route, if you can handle syncing it after the fact.